# linq max date from multiple columns and tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Objective: `table1`, `table2`, `table3` each have multiple date columns named differently.

I need to pull back the max date of these columns for the corresponding Id; a last modified date.

Can I build a let variable that is an array and then pick the max value?

Or do i need to do some case statement within the query?

Every attempt I've made has failed, looking for suggestions....

```
var query = from t1 in table1
            join t2 in table2
                on t1.Id equals t2.Id
            join t3 in table3
                on t1.Id equals t3.Id
            select new 
            {
                 Id = t1.Id
                 LastModified = <max date from multiple columns from different tables>
            };
```

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / EF Core 2.1 / EF Core 3.x?

Comment: using EF6......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding I created below code. Please have a look. Code itself contains comments:

```
 static void LinkDate()
    {
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
        table1.Columns.Add("Id");
        table1.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(System.DateTime));

        DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
        table2.Columns.Add("Id");
        table2.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(System.DateTime));

        DataTable table3 = new DataTable();
        table3.Columns.Add("Id");
        table3.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(System.DateTime));

        DataRow row = table1.NewRow();
        row[0] = "1";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("01/22/2020");
        table1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table1.NewRow();
        row[0] = "2";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("01/23/2020");
        table1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table1.NewRow();
        row[0] = "3";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("02/22/2020");
        table1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table1.NewRow();
        row[0] = "4";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("03/22/2020");
        table1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table1.NewRow();
        row[0] = "5";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("05/22/2020");
        table1.Rows.Add(row);


        row = table2.NewRow();
        row[0] = "1";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("01/25/2020");
        table2.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table2.NewRow();
        row[0] = "2";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("04/21/2020");
        table2.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table2.NewRow();
        row[0] = "3";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("02/11/2020");
        table2.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table2.NewRow();
        row[0] = "8";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("08/12/2020");
        table2.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table2.NewRow();
        row[0] = "9";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("02/25/2020");
        table2.Rows.Add(row);

        row = table3.NewRow();
        row[0] = "1";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("03/20/2020");
        table3.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table3.NewRow();
        row[0] = "2";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("01/11/2020");
        table3.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table3.NewRow();
        row[0] = "12";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("01/21/2020");
        table3.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table3.NewRow();
        row[0] = "8";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("09/22/2020");
        table3.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table3.NewRow();
        row[0] = "11";
        row[1] = Convert.ToDateTime("01/20/2020");
        table3.Rows.Add(row);


        var query = from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                    join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
                        on t1.Field<string>("Id") equals t2.Field<string>("Id")
                    join t3 in table3.AsEnumerable()
                        on t1.Field<string>("Id") equals t3.Field<string>("Id")
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = t1.Field<string>("Id"),
                        LastModified = Max(t1.Field<DateTime>("Date"), t2.Field<DateTime>("Date"), t3.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
                    };

    }
    static DateTime Max(DateTime a, DateTime b, DateTime c)
    {
        //Get max value between three.
        DateTime[] aa = { a, b, c };
        return aa.Max();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast tables to a generic type and then take the maximum date.

```
var list1 = new List<Table1>();
var list2 = new List<Table2>();
var list3 = new List<Table3>();

var lastRecord = list1.Select(x => new {Id = x.Id, DateTime = x.Dt})
            .Union(list2.Select(x => new {Id = x.Id2, DateTime = x.Date}))
            .Union(list3.Select(x => new {Id = x.Id3, DateTime = x.DateDiffName}))
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.DateTime)
            .First();
```

Comment: This approach will work, but the details are wrong for EF6.

Comment: Also, you left out the `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Alexander's approach, and switching your query to Lambda/Fluent LINQ syntax since `Union` is not (directly) available in query syntax.

First, take all the date columns from each table that you want to compare and flatten them out into separate rows:

```
var t1Dates = table1.Select(t1 => new { t1.Id, DT = t1.dc1 })
                    .Union(table1.Select(t1 => new { t1.Id, DT = t1.dc2 }));
var t2Dates = table2.Select(t2 => new { t2.Id, DT = t2.t2dc1 })
                    .Union(table2.Select(t2 => new { t2.Id, DT = t2.t2dc2 }));
var t3Dates = table3.Select(t3 => new { t3.Id, DT = t3.t3dc1 })
                    .Union(table3.Select(t3 => new { t3.Id, DT = t3.t3dc2 }));
```

Then, join the separate dates as you would originally:

```
var t123Dates = t1Dates.Join(t2Dates, t1 => t1.Id, t2 => t2.Id, (t1, t2) => new { t1.Id, DT1 = t1.DT, DT2 = t2.DT })
                       .Join(t3Dates, t12 => t12.Id, t3 => t3.Id, (t12, t3) => new { t12.Id, t12.DT1, t12.DT2, DT3 = t3.DT });
```

Then, flatten out the joined values across separate rows:

```
var tAllDates = t123Dates.Select(t123 => new { t123.Id, DT = t123.DT1 })
                         .Union(t123Dates.Select(t123 => new { t123.Id, DT = t123.DT2 }))
                         .Union(t123Dates.Select(t123 => new { t123.Id, DT = t123.DT3 }));
```

Finally, you can group the flattened result by `Id` and find the latest date that goes with each `Id`:

```
var query = tAllDates.GroupBy(ta => ta.Id)
                     .Select(tag => new {
                         Id = tag.Key,
                         LastModified = tag.OrderByDescending(ta => ta.DT).First().DT
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the `Id` and the `LastModified Date`, my advice would be to use a `Select` to select the `Id` and the `Date`, then `Orderby` descending Date and take the first one:

```
var result = dbContext.Table1.Select(row => new
{
    Id = row.Id,
    Date = row.Date,
})
.Concat(dbContext.Table2.Select(row => new
{
    Id = row.Id,
    Date = row.Date,
})
.Concat(dbContext.Table3.Select(row => new
{
    Id = row.Id,
    Date = row.Date,
})
.OrderByDescending(row => row.Date)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

In words: from every row in table1, take the Id and the Date. Do something similar for the rows in table2 and table3. Put these selected items one after another, order them by descending data, and take the first one, or null if there are no rows at all.

Simple comme bonjour!